# DateFormat for Kendo DatePicker

Tags: datepicker, kendo-ui-angular2

How can I format Kendo Date picker to MM/dd/yyyy in Angular. Also how can can I remove month/dd/yyyy watermark from date picker

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the [DatePicker `format` input](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/#toc-formats) and provide the desired formatting string, e.g.:

```
 <kendo-datepicker
                  [format]="'MM/dd/yyyy'"
                  ...
              ></kendo-datepicker>
```

[EXAMPLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ba83805RgFpenGMi8BmN?p=preview)

The placeholder comes from the current culture info, and currently cannot be removed, barring some hacks, based on clearing the underlying HTML input element's value programmatically.